# Strange error in c++ class construction

Tags: c++, class, vector, overloading

I have recently started learning c++ and I am now trying to make a simple vector class as an exercise. But somehow my code doesn't seem to work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
class Vec2
{
public:
    float x1;
    float x2;
    Vec2(float a,float b):x1(a),x2(b){}
    float norm()
    {
        return sqrt(x1*x1+x2*x2);
    }
    Vec2 operator+(const Vec2 &v)
    {
        Vec2 newv;
        newv.x1=this->x1+v.x1;
        newv.x2=this->x2+v.x2;
        return newv;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vec2 v1(3,4);
    Vec2 v2(4,5);
    Vec2 v3=v1+v2;
    std::cout << v1.x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1.norm() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v3.x1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am using eclipse as an editor and I get this error when I compile:

```
11:13:04 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project Vec2 ****
make all 
Building file: ../Vec2.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"Vec2.d" -MT"Vec2.o" -o "Vec2.o" "../Vec2.cpp"
../Vec2.cpp: In member function ‘Vec2 Vec2::operator+(const Vec2&)’:
../Vec2.cpp:15:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Vec2::Vec2()’
      Vec2 newv;
           ^~~~
../Vec2.cpp:8:2: note: candidate: Vec2::Vec2(float, float)
  Vec2(float a,float b):x1(a),x2(b){}
  ^~~~
../Vec2.cpp:8:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
../Vec2.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: constexpr Vec2::Vec2(const Vec2&)
 class Vec2
       ^~~~
../Vec2.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
../Vec2.cpp:3:7: note: candidate: constexpr Vec2::Vec2(Vec2&&)
../Vec2.cpp:3:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
make: *** [subdir.mk:20: Vec2.o] Error 1

11:13:05 Build Finished (took 422ms)
```

I suspect the operator overloading is the culprit here but I can't seem to get it to run.
Any ideas would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Provide a default constructor for your class and you are good to go

Comment: operator overloading is unrelated to your issue. You need to read more about constructors (e.g. the [C++ rule of five](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either create default constructor

```
Vec2() {}
```

or you can change lines 15-17 to

```
Vec2 newv(this->x1+v.x1, newv.x2=this->x2+v.x2);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class lacks a default constructor. Simply add one and you're done

```
class Vec2
{
public:
    float x1;
    float x2;
    Vec2() {}  // default constructor
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with operator overloading. The error message will help you understand that it is a constructor issue.

From [this](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSLTBW_2.1.0/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.cbclx01/cplr376.htm) reference, if you have a user-defined constructor, the default constructor does not exist for that class. Hence, your program is expecting arguments in the constructor, which you have not provided.

The fix would be to define a default constructor, along with the one you have already defined. This way you can use both.

```
Vec2() {}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

We don't need a default constructor for this class. 
This means that user can not create object without x,y argument..
I think it can be good reason if you intended to make user that way.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
class Vec2
{
public:
    float x1;
    float x2;
    Vec2(float a,float b):x1(a),x2(b){}
    float norm()
    {
        return sqrt(x1*x1+x2*x2);
    }
    Vec2 operator+(const Vec2 &v)
    {
        float x1=this->x1+v.x1;
        float x2=this->x2+v.x2;
        Vec2 newv(x1,x2);
        return newv;
    }
};
int main()
{
    Vec2 v1(3,4);
    Vec2 v2(4,5);
    Vec2 v3=v1+v2;
    std::cout << v1.x1 << std::endl;
    std::cout << v1.norm() << std::endl;
    std::cout << v3.x1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[image]